# How to update Bamboo plan or global variable using REST API?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I've been searching for how to do this for a long time now without any luck. Does anyone know how to update a plan/global variable using Bamboo's REST API? I'm NOT talking about passing a variable into a build, I want to update the variable so that the value sticks permanently, not just for the duration of the build. This feature seems to be part of the REST API (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-9344), but it's not documented anywhere in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Just update bin/setenv.sh file by adding  -Datlassian.darkfeature.bamboo.experimental.rest.admin.enabled=true property to JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS variable. Then restart Bamboo. Now try to access  https://{bamboo_url}/rest/admin/latest/globalVariables/. You should be able to get list of all global variables. 
For testing this, I created new Global Variable 'client' with value 'Mark' and when I run https://{bamboo_url}/rest/admin/latest/globalVariables/, I get json , which shows all values like id, name , value for newly added Global Variable .

Next step would be updating existing variable. I used REST API browser for this, but I am sure,  you can update using CURL command too.
Here are the steps, 
1)open Rest API browser and uncheck checkbox which says 'show only public APIs'
2) search for Globalvraibles, you have to use admin/1.0/globalVariables/{variableId}. so select this one and go to PUT tab.
3) Enter variableID(which you already got) and request body. 
4) click on send and variable is updated.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@test.json" -X PUT -u username:password "https://localhost:8085/rest/admin/latest/globalVariables/{variableID}"

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is Cloud instance of Bamboo. Will this solution still work in the Cloud instance?

Comment: It should work. But this REST API is private, hence not supported by Atlassian. I don't recommend using it for Plugin development.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. Cloud instances are controlled by Atlassian and we cannot remote into them. If you have an alternative solution, I'd like to try it out.

Comment: Bamboo cloud doesn't support this feature yet. It might be available in coming releases. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/35774012/how-to-update-plan-or-global-variable-using-rest-api

Comment: Thanks, I actually posted that inquiry. If you'll notice, it's the exact same text as this SO question.